# Is it possible to iterate multiple data sets async BeginExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous

I have a long running stored procedure that returns multiple results.

I'd like to iterate the results asynchronously and grab results as they are ready (AS THEY ARE AVAILABLE).

`ExecuteReaderAsync` with some `WaitOne` logic? (never used this so any example is appreciated)

Is this possible?

```
private IEnumerable<DataTable> validationResultSets(string MOName, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, string FilePath)
{
    DataTable d;
    using (SqlConnection conn =
    new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.sp_ValidateAcceptanceFile", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@MOName",
                Value = MOName,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Size = 255
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@StartDate",
                Value = StartDate,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@EndDate",
                Value = EndDate,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime
            });

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@FilePath",
                Value = FilePath,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                Size = 500
            });

            //IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            IDataReader rdr = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(); //??
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    d = new DataTable();
                    d.Load(rdr);
                    yield return d;
                } while (!rdr.IsClosed);
            }
            finally
            {
                rdr.Close();
                rdr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ended up splitting it out into separate sps and wonkering the temp table strategy into named table with job id tags. what a shame :-(

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts. A procedure returning multiple results is not related in any way to MARS. A procedure returning multiple results can be invoked asynchronously, note that your async call will complete as soon as the first fragment of the result has returned from the server and from there on you read the results just like in the sync code.

Comment: Try async await, is easier: [ExecuteReaderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync.aspx). Read [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx). Requires .Net 4.5

Comment: I want to iterate them as the become available